# dismissViewControllerAnimated leaves black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've read a number of threads on stackoverflow about this issue, but none seemed to have a fix that worked for my most basic and straightforward case.

I'm using XCode 7.2.1 and iOS 9.2

I have a class (code shown below) that accepts a `UIViewController` to use as the presenter of a `UINavigationController`.

This code below is from ONE class, and it does both the presenting and dismissing.

Starting with screen 1 pictured below, the user taps a button in the upper left corner, which then presents the `UINavigationController` in screen 2.  Finally, tapping the "Done" button in the upper right corner of the `UINavigationController` (screen 2) causes a black screen... screen 3.

Lastly, you'll notice on the black screen a little red circle with a number in it.
That is from the tab bar in screen 1 at the bottom.  For some reason it stacked up all the tab bar buttons in the corner, and left a little area for them to peek out.

```
-(id)initWithDashboardParentViewController:(TabMapController*)mapVC propertyDelegate:(id<iRpPropertyDelegate>)propertyDelegate
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {
            mapViewController = mapVC;
            thePropertyDelegate = propertyDelegate;
        }
        return self;
    }


-(void)displaySpreadsheetOfAllSubitems
    {
        UIViewController *theContentController;

        // Create a generic gridview view controller and initialize it with the data that will be shown.
        theContentController = [[iRpGenericGridViewController alloc] initWithPropertyDelegate:propertyDelegate dashboardDataItem:spreadsheetTableData];

        theContentController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        // Create a navigation controller and embed the content view controller.
        UINavigationController *theNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theContentController];

        // If a detail item was found for this section, then display it in the navigation controller.
        if (theNavController)
        {
            // Set up the 'Done' navigation bar button.
            theNavController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(detailDisclosureDone)];

            [mapViewController presentViewController:theNavController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
        }
    }



-(void)detailDisclosureDone
    {
        [mapViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did figure out that it has something to do with AutoLayout and the constraints set on my root view controller.

I made a constraint that the root view controller has to be at least a given height, instead of just saying it was 0-nearestSuperview, etc, and now I'm seeing a portion of my view.